# How do i create the proper syntax for a trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm new to SQL.  I may not be using the right terms.  I'm trying to create a SQL trigger so that if there is a decrease in the percentage of one item in the column (Population) of a table (City)  there is a corresponding decrease in the percentage of  another column (Population) in another table (Continent).   Any help or tips would be great.  Below if my code so far.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER test 
       BEFORE UPDATE ON City 
       FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF City.Population = > (.9*(City.Population)) THEN SET Country.Continent =             (Country.Continent * 0.95) ; 
       END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Every if has to have an end if; and I would expect to see reference to NEW. values AND you need some logic to deal with country

Comment: This is a really odd requirement.  Wouldn't you want the "continent" population to match the sum of the populations of the entities that comprise the continent?